# Adding a number to the end of a URL and increasing it every time its (re)loaded

Tags: iframe

Its been driving me insane i have being trying to fix this up since the transport department changed their system. To have this still work on our site we need to have .jpg?[number] the number cant be the same as the last and needs to increase every time it image is viewed or refreshed. I have no clue about coding, nor have i found anything helpful to allow me to learn how to fix this.

Can anyone help at all?